# Build TensorFlow on Jetson TX2

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, bazel, arm64, nvidia-jetson

I'm trying [this tutorial](https://www.jetsonhacks.com/2018/03/26/build-tensorflow-on-nvidia-jetson-tx-development-kits/) but I had some compile error.
Can anyone give me some advice, please?

My environment is...

- Ubuntu 16.04
- JetsonTX2
- Architecture aarch64
- JetPack 3.2
- CUDA 9.0
- cuDNN 7.0.5

I did the following command:

```
$ sudo -H bash BuildTensorflow.sh -b r1.6
```

and the error is...

```
    swapon: /home/nvidia/JetsonTFBuild/swapfile.swap: swapon failed: Device or resource busy
    Looks like Swap not desired or is already in use
    dirname: missing operand
    Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
    dirname: missing operand
    Try 'dirname --help' for more information.
    PYTHON_BIN_PATH=/usr/bin/python2
    GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH=/usr/bin/gcc
    CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=
    TF_CUDA_VERSION=9.0
    TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES=5.3,6.2
    CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH=/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
    TF_CUDNN_VERSION=7.0.5
    ./tf_build.sh: line 20: /home/nvidia/JetsonTFBuild: Is a directory
    /usr/bin/python2: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    error: patch failed: tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD:21
    error: tensorflow/contrib/lite/kernels/internal/BUILD: patch does not apply
    INFO: Options provided by the client:
            Inherited 'common' options: --isatty=1 --terminal_columns=80
    INFO: Reading rc options for 'build' from /home/nvidia/JetsonTFBuild/tensorflow/tools/bazel.rc:
            'build' options: --define framework_shared_object=true --define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --define=allow_oversize_protos=true --define=grpc_no_ares=true --spawn_strategy=standalone --genrule_strategy=standalone -c opt
    ERROR: Config value opt is not defined in any .rc file
    Tue Oct 9 20:34:03 JST 2018 : === Using tmpdir: /tmp/tmp.swhwrsSoaA
    cp: cannot stat 'bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/build_pip_package.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow': No such file or directory
```